# Moving MongoDB dbpath to an AWS EBS device

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, docker

I'm using CentOS 7 via AWS.

I'd like to store MongoDB data on an attached EBS instead of the default /var/lib path.

However, when I edit `/etc/mongod.conf` to point to a new *dbpath*, I'm getting a permission denied error.

Permissions are set correctly to mongod.mongod on the dir.

What gives?

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR - The issue is SELinux, which affects what daemons can access. Run `setenforce 0` to temporarily disable.**

You're using a flavour of Linux that uses SELinux.

From Wikipedia:

> SELinux can potentially control which activities a system allows each
>   user, process and daemon, with very precise specifications. However,
>   it is mostly used to confine daemons[citation needed] like database
>   engines or web servers that have more clearly defined data access and
>   activity rights. This limits potential harm from a confined daemon
>   that becomes compromised. Ordinary user-processes often run in the
>   unconfined domain, not restricted by SELinux but still restricted by
>   the classic Linux access rights

**To fix temporarily:**

```
sudo setenforce 0
```

This should disable SELinux policies and allow the service to run.

**To fix permanently:**

Edit `/etc/sysconfig/selinux` and set this:

`SELINUX=disabled`

Then reboot.

The service should now start-up fine.

The data dir will also work with Docker, i.e. something like:

`docker run --name db -v /mnt/path-to-mounted-ebs:/data/db -p 27017:27017 mongo:latest`

***Warning: Both solutions DISABLE the security that SELinux provides, which will weaken your overall security. A better solution is to understand how SELinux works, and create a policy on your new data dir that works with mongod. See https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinux for a more complete tutorial.***